# Replace excel column values by values in another file

Tags: python, excel, matlab

I have a excel file with these columns: v1,v2,commID

[image: File 1]

I have another file with columns: Index, Name

[image: File 2]

Now I want to replace v1 and v2 with corresponding names by referring to second file and write it in a new file.The format is v1,v2,commID, but this time v1 and v2 should be names whereas commID should be the same numbers. I can do it in excel or python or matlab.

Comment: You only have one "name", do you want the same value to be repeated in v1 & v2 ? This also sounds like a classic SQL problem. You also don't mention what research you have already done on this problem. This site wasn't meant for "homework" questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose you two solutions: one for Excel and one for Matlab. Pick the one you prefer (if you don't need to process data with Matlab, I recommend you to go for the first solution and stick on Excel).

**EXCEL**

Sticking on Excel in order solve this problem, I would go for a manual approach. The only function you would have to use, in this case, is [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/181213/how-to-use-vlookup-or-hlookup-to-find-an-exact-match). Let's see how to proceed step by step:

1. Create a new Excel file.
2. Open the first file (the one with `v1`, `v2` and `commID` columns) and copy-paste its content in the first sheet of the new file.
3. Open the second file (the one with `Index` and `Name`) and copy-paste its content in the second sheet of the new file.
4. Go back to the first sheet.
5. Insert the string `v1` in column `D` row `1` (for replicating the header). Insert the following formula in column `D` row `2`: `=VLOOKUP(A2;B!A:B;2;FALSE)` and replicate it down to the bottom.
6. Insert the string `v2` in column `E` row `1` (for replicating the header). Insert the following formula in column `E` row `2`: `=VLOOKUP(B2;B!A:B;2;FALSE)` and replicate it down to the bottom.
7. Select the whole `D` and `E` columns (the remapped `v1` and `v2`) and copy their content (`CTRL+C`). Now, select the whole `A` and `B` columns (the old `v1` and `v2`) and paste the previously copied content in place (use the `Paste Values` special feature from the context menu).
8. Remove the last two columns of the sheet. Delete the second and the third sheets. Save your file.

**MATLAB**

Since your problem is very close to a `SQL` join operation, I would go for tables (obtained by parsing the Excel files using the [readtable](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) function) and the built-in [join](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.join.html#namevaluepairarguments) function:

```
% Read the content of both Excel files...
F1 = readtable('File1.xlsx');
F2 = readtable('File2.xlsx');

% Join the table F1 with F2 on v1 = Index...
T1 = join(F1,F2,'LeftKeys',{'v1'},'RightKeys',{'Index'});

% Join the table F1 with F2 on v2 = Index...
T2 = join(F1,F2,'LeftKeys',{'v2'},'RightKeys',{'Index'});

% Create the final table combining T1.Name (as v1), T2 (as v2) and F1.commID (as commID)...
T = table(T1.Name,T2.Name,F1.commID,'VariableNames',{'v1' 'v2' 'commID'});

% Save the result into a new file...
writetable(T,'File3.xlsx');
```

Let's suppose the content of the first file (`File1.xlsx`) is:

```
v1    v2    commID
__    __    ______

2     1     1     
2     1     1     
3     4     1     
3     5     2     
1     4     1
```

and the content of the second file (`File2.xlsx`) is:

```
Index    Name 
_____    _____

1        'AAA'
2        'BBB'
3        'CCC'
4        'DDD'
5        'EEE'
```

Then the final output would be:

```
 v1       v2      commID
_____    _____    ______

'BBB'    'AAA'    1     
'BBB'    'AAA'    1     
'CCC'    'DDD'    1     
'CCC'    'EEE'    2     
'AAA'    'DDD'    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, change the names of files and stuff as needed but this worked for me! This uses openpyxl which I believe is included in the Anaconda distribution of python. Also, this is likely not the best way to do it, but it works.

```
import openpyxl

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename="wb1.xlsx")
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename="wb2.xlsx")
output_file = openpyxl.Workbook()

dest_filename = "outputWorkbook.xlsx"

commIDlist, nameList = [], []
for item in wb1['Sheet1']['C']:
    commIDlist.append(item.value)

for item in wb2['Sheet1']['B']:
    nameList.append(item.value)

ws1 = output_file.active
ws1.title = "Data Ouput"

i = 0
j = 0
for row in range(1, len(nameList)):
    _ = ws1.cell(column=1, row=row, value=nameList[i])
    j += 0

for row in range(1, len(commIDlist)):
    _ = ws1.cell(column=2, row=row, value=commIDlist[i])
    i += 1

output_file.save(filename=dest_filename)
```